# How to check from User Up if a Site2 has a session on other server in PHP

Tags: php, api, curl

thanks for reading this. My problem goes like this.

1. (site1) I Call the server via Curl with my APP ID
2. (site2) Server Gets APP ID and the Current $_SESSION of the "Logged User" (WONT WORK)
3. (site2) access.php Returns a JSON  { "user_token": "12312312312" }
4. (Site1) Reads the Json and parses it and if user_token is NULL then i show a LOGIN BUTTON else I SHOW USER PROFILE.

But this is not working because the $_SESSION is not giving the current session.

Does any one knows any way around this?

thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Your cURL call isn't seen as belonging to the correct session on site 2. Most likely this is, because you didn't send the session ID - it is either in a cookie or in the URL. There is no way to associate a request with a session, if the SID is not given. Soy ou have to:

- Get the Session ID of the user on **site 2** into the request for **site 1**. This will need some quite heavy plumbing.
- Include this session ID in your call to **site 1**
- On **site 1** extract the session ID and use it for the cURL request

Answer (score 0):

In order for site2 to be able to access the session information, you need to pass the cookie that site2 expect.  Cookies are used to keep track of sessions.

With curl, you can pass the cookie with headers.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "cookiename=cookievalue");
```

Or you can use the cookiejar or cookiefile as well.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookieFileLocation); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookieFileLocation);
```